# PHP logout need solution

Tags: php, html

im going to programm a Backend for one of my projects. Yesterday i made the login and logout function. In the Backed there is a navigation point calles logout:

```
 if (isset($_GET['act'])) {
$selection = $_GET['act'];

switch ($selection) {
    case "home":
    include("include/home.php");
    break;
    case "registration":
    include("include/registration.php");
    break;
    case "cusadm":
    include("include/cusadm.php");
    break;
    case "history":
    include("include/history.php");
    break;
    case "logout":
    include("include/logout.php");
    break;
    default:
    include("include/home.php");
```

logout.php

```
<?php 
$_SESSION = array();
header('Location:index.php');
?>
```

my problem is now that f.e my form has now links and every link do a logout.

here is a screenshot:
http://s13.postimage.org/s4k7akc5j/problem.jpg

so how can i solve this problem?

Comment: is your anchor tag to logout really enclosing the entire registration form? maybe change it to `<a href="index.php?act=logout">LOGOUT</a>` to make it a link that can be used to logout

Comment: jep its enclosing the entire registration form also every other text. dunno how i could change it cause im including this site into my index.php in switch case

Comment: Might be that your click inside the registration form is bubbling up and triggering the anchor tag as well, causing the logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you haven't closed an anchor tag or something like that.

Check your markup: http://validator.w3.org

Comment: no everything is fine, also when i choose home. my home.php just includes an echo "test"; and is marked as a link with logout.

Comment: ok solved my problem. in my navigation.php the <a> anchor wasnt closed. Thanks for you help =)